Unicode glyphs not rendering on Manjaro i3
I cannot get Unicode glyphs to render on Monjaro i3.
I have installed a bunch of noto fonts, including noto-fonts, noto-fonts-cjk, noto-fonts-emoji, noto-fonts-extra, ttf-noto-nerd.
When I run fc-match with an unrecognised Unicode character, it supposedly matches the correct font. This is for U+F312:
fc-match ""                                                                                                                                                                                      
NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"

I have run fc-cache -fv and rebooted multiple times.
fc-cache -fv
Font directories:
    /home/aidanb/.local/share/fonts
    /usr/local/share/fonts
    /usr/share/fonts
    /var/lib/snapd/desktop/fonts
    /home/aidanb/.fonts
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF
    /usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro
    /usr/share/fonts/cantarell
    /usr/share/fonts/droid
    /usr/share/fonts/encodings
    /usr/share/fonts/gsfonts
    /usr/share/fonts/liberation
    /usr/share/fonts/misc
    /usr/share/fonts/noto
    /usr/share/fonts/noto-cjk
    /usr/share/fonts/encodings/large
/home/aidanb/.local/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/local/share/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 11 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/OTF: caching, new cache contents: 23 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/TTF: caching, new cache contents: 554 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro: caching, new cache contents: 30 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell: caching, new cache contents: 6 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/droid: caching, new cache contents: 27 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/encodings: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 1 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/encodings/large: caching, new cache contents: 0 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts: caching, new cache contents: 35 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/liberation: caching, new cache contents: 12 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/misc: caching, new cache contents: 125 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/noto: caching, new cache contents: 2137 fonts, 0 dirs
/usr/share/fonts/noto-cjk: caching, new cache contents: 80 fonts, 0 dirs
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/fonts: skipping, no such directory
/home/aidanb/.fonts: skipping, no such directory
/usr/share/fonts/OTF: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/TTF: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/adobe-source-code-pro: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/cantarell: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/droid: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/encodings: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/gsfonts: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/liberation: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/misc: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/noto: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/noto-cjk: skipping, looped directory detected
/usr/share/fonts/encodings/large: skipping, looped directory detected
/var/cache/fontconfig: not cleaning unwritable cache directory
/home/aidanb/.cache/fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
/home/aidanb/.fontconfig: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded

Here's my current version:
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID="ManjaroLinux"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="24.1.2"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="Xahea"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"

Please help! Thank you.
